# vb.net: Select the data stored in my.settings properties

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am new to vb.net programming.
Is there any possible way to query SELECT the data stored in my.settings?

Example value in my.settings: 'SN-16-0002'.

In my query i just want the last 4 digit, pls help

I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  'value is 'SN-16-0002'

     dim y = My.Settings.value.Substring(value.Length - 4)
```

[My.Settings Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saa62613.aspx)

[String.Substring Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx)